# Capturar em Loop o valor de uma varivel de outra Activity

Tags: android

Na minha app, tenho uma atividade chamada "`GpsTrackerActivity`" que está constantemente a calcular a distancia percorrida através do método `onLocationChanged`, da Interface `LocationListener`.

O meu problema é que necessito de abrir uma nova actividade e quero que esta, enquanto estiver activa, consiga capturar em Loop o valor da variável pública "`distancia`", que está na actividade "`GpsTrackerActivity`".
Já tentei um ciclo *While* infinito para ficar constantemente a capturar o valor da variável "distancia", mas desta forma a app bloqueia! Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
public class GpsTrackerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {
public static double distancia;
....
}
```

Segunda Atividade:

```
public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

while (true){
            double distancia = GpsTrackerActivity.distancia;
            Log.i("Tag", "Distância: " + distancia + " Km");
        }

}
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer, até  onde sei, não é possível, pois cada activity tem seu próprio contexto ( conjunto de recursos e classes próprias), além disso, só é possível executar uma Activity por vez, então é inviável capturar os eventos de uma *Activity A* que esá "fechada" dentro de uma *Activity B* que está aberta. Portanto, se você quiser que alguma activity capture o evento de "localização alterada", é ela mesma quem deve "escutar" e tratar as alterações na localização.

Como no seu caso as duas activities precisam receber alterações na localização, você tem duas opções:

1. **Ao obter a nova localização na** `GPSTrackerActivity`**, inicar a segunda activity pasando a localização obtida através de um** `Bundle`

   Nesse caso, ao obter a nova localização com o método `onLocationChanged(Location location)` na `GPSTrackerActivity`, você faria:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       // Calcule a sua distancia   
       // double distancia = ?     

       Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
       mBundle.putDouble("distancia",distancia);

       Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class)    
              mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);

       startActivity(mIntent);
   }
   ```

   E na `SegundaActivity` você pegaria a distância passada no método `onCreate()` utilizando o seguinte código

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       double distancia = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("distancia");

       /* ... */
   }
   ```

   **OBS.:** *Note que, nesse caso, a sua `SegundaActivity` só recebe uma única distância, que foi obtida a partir da última localização recebida pela `GPSTrackerActivity`. Isso significa que, se a sua localização mudar enquanto a `SegundaActivity` estiver aberta, ela não receberá essa nova distância, pois quem recebe e trata a distância é a `GPSTrackerActivity`. Se você  quiser que a `SegundaActivity` receba constantemente uma nova localização conforme haja mudanças, você pode usar a segunda abordagem.*
2. **Criar uma classe " `MeuLocationManager` " que será responsável por acompanhar mudanças na localização e fornece-las a um "solicitante"**

   Nesse caso, você irá transferir toda a lógica do acompanhamento de mudanças na localização para a classe " `MeuLocationManager` ". Assim, toda vez que uma classe quiser receber informações sobre mudanças na localização, basta requisitar ao " `MeuLocationManager` " que envie a ela as localizações obtidas. Fica mais ou menos assim:

   ```
    public class MeuLocationManager implements LocationListener /*, etc. */ {

        // Classe que vai requisitar a localização
        private LocationListener requisitorLocalizacao;  

        /* Vamos implementar o padrão Singleton para evitar que 
           um novo LocationManager seja criado a cada vez que for
           necessário chamá-lo*/

        private static MeuLocationManager instance;

        private MeuLocationManager() {

        /* Implemente e/ou crie todos os métodos necessários 
           para obtenção de localização, como:

           Criação e inicialização do Google Services
           Callbacks para escutar a conexão com o Google Services, etc. */
        }

        public static MeuLocationManager getInstance(){

            if(instance == null){
                return new MeuLocationManager();
            }else{
                return instance;
            }
        }

       /* Método que será usado por outra classe para solicitar
        a localização */
       public void requestLocationUpdates(LocationListener requisitorLocalizacao){

           this.requisitorLocalizacao = requisitorLocalizacao;
       }

       /* Repassa a localização obtida para o requisitor da
       localização */
       @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

            // Repassa a localização obtida para o requisitor da
            // localizacao
            requisitorLocalizacao.onLocationChanged(location);
       }
   }
   ```

   Agora, toda classe que quiser receber mudanças na localização, deverá implementar a interface `LocationListener` e solicitar ao `MeuLocationManager` que envie a ela as novas localizações obtidas. Vamos utilizar como exemplo a sua classe `SegundaActivity`. Primeiro, você deve fazer ela implementar a interface `LocationListener`, em seguida você fará o seguinte no seu método `onCreate()`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       MeuLocationManager locationManager = MeuLocationManager.getInstance();

       // Solicita localização
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this);
   }

   // No método `onLocationChanged` faça o que você quiser 
   // com a localização que foi recebida do MeuLocationManager
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       /* ... */
   }
   ```

Essas são apenas duas soluções possíveis, existem muitas outras, como por exemplo, utilizar a biblioteca [Reactive Location](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation), que é a que eu uso nos meus projetos :)

Comment: regmorais, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, pois foi excelente a sua explicação. Vou optar pela segunda abordagem.

Comment: regmorais, só não percebi na Classe MeuLocationManager a configuração  public static MeuLocationListener getInstance(){...}? Ao inseri-lo na Classe obtenho um erro por causa do nome  MeuLocationListener?

Comment: @VitorMendanha me desculpe, eu coloquei o nome errado, o certo é **MeuLocationManager**. Já consertei na resposta :)